# cant get data to save using element host

Tags: c#, wpf

In my winform app, I'm using elementhost to display the xaml. The xaml uses properties from a viewmodel. Unfortunately, when I click on the save button, (this button is a winform button), I'm not able to get any data I typed in the xaml. Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do it just in case someone may come across this issue.

```
CarView car = (CarView) CarHost.Child;
        CarViewModel cvm = (CarViewModel) car.DataContext;
```