# How can I call a WPF command from a Winform's Button?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I'm using both winform and incorporating wpf through `ElementHost`.

How can I call a WPF `ICommand` from a Winforms button's click event? These are all new to me so bear with me with these kind of questions.

My current code is

```
CarView car = (CarView) CarHost.Child;         
CarViewModel cvm = (CarViewModel) car.DataContext;
cvm.SaveCommand.Execute(null);
```

So by doing that I was able to call the `SaveCommand`, but I dont get any data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Once you have the ICommand instance you just call Execute on it, or if you want CanExecute then Execute.

Comment: @Adam Mills -- I'm not following you. Can you give me an example?

Comment: Why not just use the button's `Command` property instead of using the `Click` event?

Comment: @Rachel -- becuase I dont have any property call Command for my button. Keep in mind that the button I want to call to the ICommand is not a located in the xaml. It's just on a regular form as a regular button. Again I'm using elementhost to show the xaml.

Comment: @Rachel because he's using WinForms for this section but trying to access the ICommands from a hosted WPF control. He mentioned that in the reply to my answer below.

Comment: Why are you asking the question twice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159119/cant-get-data-to-save-using-element-host

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be missing something here. Normally you'd do something like:

```
<Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
```

And then when someone clicks the button, MyCommand's Execute method is called.

I suppose, from a codebehind, you could call:

```
private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MyCommand.CanExecute(null))
        MyCommand.Execute(null);
}
```

But except for very specific circumstances (which you haven't mentioned) I'm not sure why you'd do it that way. I think you definitely need to give us a little more information.

Comment: I'm using both winform and incorporating wpf through elementhost. By doing so I want to call the icommand from the click event of the code behind.

Comment: ok, well then, you'd want to do what I showed in the C# code. I passed in null because I was assuming no parameter, but you can also pass in your parameter.